# what's "lf clause" in the sentence "that would suggest..."?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> That would suggest that the ancestor of all living things LUCA was
>   made of DNA.

The phrase "that would suggest ..." is a conditional sentence. But I can not define the if clause.
So could you please explain it to me?

The fuller text is here:

> Ida and Luca existed so long ago that if any rocks ever harboured
>   traces of their existence, they were long ago subsumed by tectonic
>   forces and melted into Earth’s depths. But we can find clues to their
>   nature in every living cell today, including our own. Cells use the
>   same genetic code embodied in DNA. **That would suggest that** the
>   ancestor of all living things, Luca, was made of DNA.

Comment: I don't see an "if-clause" in there. Its a simple sentence: This suggests that Luca was made of DNA.

Comment: Are you saying "But we can find clues" means "there is a possibility of finding clues ... *if we do find clues to their nature in our cells* that would suggest that luca was made of DNA"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"That would suggest" is not necessarily part of an if-clause.  Instead it's a sentence fragment (not a complete sentence in itself) that is a logical consequence of the previous assertion.  Paraphrasing:

> Since all the cells of living organisms contain the same embedded DNA, **that would suggest** their common ancestor (Luca) also had the same DNA.

It would be possible to rewrite this is an if-then statement:

> **If** true that all the cells of living organisms contain the same DNA, **that would suggest** their common ancestor (Luca) also had the same DNA.

Note:  This paragraph is not particularly well-written, as it contains numerous redundancies, sentence fragments, and misused words (e.g. "embodied" rather than "embedded").  The author may not be a native speaker, or perhaps just a careless writer.  I would not worry too much if you read things in the text that seem strange.